# Is there another way to test XPATH strings aside from $x?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

It appears `$x` is being overwritten by code in the page I am currently working with -- I can't use `$x('//xpath-goes-here')` to return anything from the page.

I know that `$()` is an alias for `document.querySelector()`, but I can't find if `$x()` is an alias for another method I can use instead.

Is there another way using chrome dev tools to test what an XPATH string will return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the devtools Elements inspector find tool: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> or ⌘F, then type your xpath query and the matching elements will be highlighted:

[image]

Or re-implement the [native functionality](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/inspector/main_thread_debugger.cc?l=434-478&rcl=a69b1e27162b4eb48ae5ee6bbbe9d4214a0be9eb) using [document.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/evaluate) under a new name like `$$x`:

```js
function $$x(xpath, root = document) {
  const x = document.evaluate(xpath, root, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  if (x.resultType === XPathResult.STRING_TYPE)
    return x.stringValue;
  if (x.resultType === XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE)
    return x.numberValue;
  if (x.resultType === XPathResult.BOOLEAN_TYPE)
    return x.booleanValue;
  const results = [];
  let node;
  while ((node = x.iterateNext()))
    results.push(node);
  return results;
}
```

Store this code in [devtools snippets panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets) with `$$x` name so you can quickly inject it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or ⌘P. After that you'll be able to use it in the console.